# Django exception: Improperly configured SECRET_KEY

Tags: python, django

While executing migrate command `'python manage.py migrate'` on mac os, I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/final-tribute/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/final-tribute/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/final-tribute/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/final-tribute/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 61, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/final-tribute/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/final-tribute/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 72, in handle
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/final-tribute/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/final-tribute/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/final-tribute/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 129, in __init__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

I have mentioned a SECRET_KEY = 'fooo' in my base.py file

base.py

```
import os
import smtplib

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
SITE_NAME = 'final-tribute'

# Allow all host headers
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'profiles.Profile'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/profiles/'
LOGIN_URL = '/'

ADMINS = (
    ('Ab Rao', 'abc@abc.in')
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# Application definition

DJANGO_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.postgres',
    # 'social.apps.django_app.default',
)

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = (
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'social.apps.django_app.default',
    'micawber.contrib.mcdjango',
    'paypal.standard.ipn',
    # 'django_extensions',
    # 'storages',
)

LOCAL_APPS = (
    'core',
    'login',
    'profiles',
    'tributes',
    'testimonials',
    'anecdotes',
    'family_tree',
    'timeline',
    'gallery',
    'general',
    'customauth',
    'myapp'
)

INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + LOCAL_APPS

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'core.get_username.RequestMiddleware'
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ft.urls'
HOST_URL = os.environ.get('HOST_URL')
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ft.wsgi.application'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'customauth.User'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

# -------------------------------------------------------
#
# Settings to be set in local/prod/staging setting files
#
# --------------------------------------------------------
SECRET_KEY = "foo"
DEBUG = False
DATABASES = {
    #'default': {
     #   'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
      #  'NAME': 'db',
       # 'USER': 'user',
        #'PASSWORD': 'db_user',
        #'HOST': 'localhost',
        #'PORT': '3306',
    }
}

PAYPAL_TEST = True

# AWS Settings
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = ""
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = ""
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'finaltribute-dev'
MEDIA_URL = 'http://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage"
# --------------------------------------------------------

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

# Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
#MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media_root')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]


# Rest framework settings
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'PAGINATE_BY': 10,
    'PAGINATE_BY_PARAM': 'page_size',
    'MAX_PAGINATE_BY': 100,
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend',
    ),
}

# temp <- FIXME this needs to go into local/prod/staging files.
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST')
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_PORT = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PORT')
BASIC_WWW_AUTHENTICATION_USERNAME = "ftwalla"
BASIC_WWW_AUTHENTICATION_PASSWORD = "ftwalla"
BASIC_WWW_AUTHENTICATION = True
```

Error has also mentioned the path of file *init*.py

*init*.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

Also my manage.py looks like this -

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

I tried several things including export SECRET_KEY = 'foo',but nothing worked-out.

Also the same error appears on the runserver command.

Comment: Your question mentions `base.py`, so it looks like you're not using a simple `settings.py`. Please add more information about this.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the settings you are using when running the server or any command (including migrations).

Example: `python manage.py runserver --settings=app.settings.local`

Answer (score 0):

This error may happen due to a circular dependency of the settings module (ex. a *middleware* class which is loaded in the *settings* that also tries to load the *settings* module).